# Flutter RegEx to input text

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create `RegEx` to accept only number not (comma, dots and other symbol)?

**Is there any online generator for that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that flutter gives solution, within your TextField add below property it’ll not allow user to enter any character which is not number

```
TextField(

  …

keyboardType: TextInputType.number,


inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
            ],
```

or

```
TextField(

  …

keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

inputFormatters:[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
```